# How to install SD Card and ethernet at uClinux

Tags: fpga, uclinux

I have just installed uCLinux at Altera DE2-115 (FPGA BOARD), I have full access to the terminal, the things that happen:

I want to set an IP and also MASK for my eth0, when I do "ifconfig" it only shows me:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

there is no eth0 or eth1, and there are two ethernet ports, the eth0 have a ethernet cable plugged in (fully working with internet and lan network).

why there are no eth0 or eth1?

also:
when I want to mount my SD-card Drive I do the following:

```
mkdir /mnt/sd
mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/sd
```

and I get:

```
mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 on /mnt/sd failed: No such device or address
```

as if there was no SD Card device... in my dev folder there are the followings:

```
mmc0
mmcblk0
mmcblk0p1
mmcblk0p2
mmcblk0p3
```

and I have tried mounting with every single one of them, also the SD Card Drive supports FAT16 and that is the file system Iam using at the moment on my SD Card.

What can I do to be able to access the ethernet "eth0" and/or "eth1", and SD Card?

Answer (score 0):

You need a couple of things for ethernet on Linux:

1. The hardware (magnetics + phy), this seem exist in your case o.k.
2. Some FPGA design which connect the hardware to your processor. This is often called IP core. You can compare it with the network card in a PC.
3. A piece of software which must meet the ethernet IP core. In Linux this is the proper driver.

Are you sure that piece 2 is in your hardware design?
Are you sure you have the proper driver in linux activated?